# Integrar MercadoPago

Tags: java, android, mercadopago

Estoy tratando de integrar MercadoPago a mi app pero siempre sucede lo mismo:

```
Failed to resolve: com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.86.0
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error mostrado:

```
Failed to resolve: com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.86.0
```

Build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.86.0'
```

¿Alguien sabe que hago mal?

**Actualización:**

El `minSDK` que utilizo es el **26**.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.frabasoft.mitaller"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

El build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}
```

Comment: Saludos Franqo Balsamo, aquí te dejo unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 estoy seguro que la pregunta mejorará y eso incrementa la chance de obtener una mejor respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta @fredyfx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a el mensaje mostrado:

> Failed to resolve: com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.86.0

La dependencia no puede ser reconocida, probablemente la versiòn no existe o no tienes conexiòn a internet para descargarla.

Si revisas la [documentaciòn de Mercado Pago](https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android) puedes ver que indica agregar en la secciòn de dependencias:

```
implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.+'
```

Pero esto es en realidad incorrecto lo correcto es especificar la versiòn, de otra forma obtendràs este aviso:

> Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and
> unrepeatable builds (com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.+)

Pero en este caso para esta dependencia, la tienes que definir de esta forma:

```
implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.+'
```

pero en tu `build.gradle` debes usar `minSdkVersion 19` :

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        
        minSdkVersion 19
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

de esta forma podràs descargar sin problema la dependencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hice los cambios como sugieres pero la verdad es que el problema persiste, he actualizado la pregunta añadiendo los build.gradle

Comment: Veo que agregaste el build.gradle, este problema no se refiere al agregar correctamente o no la dependencia. Voy a revisar de acuerdo tu configuraciòn

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Cambia a  minSdkVersion 19 y define la dependencia como: implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.+'

Comment: Vos sabes que sigue sin funcionarme, me tira el mismo error. Voy a probar creando un proyecto desde 0

Answer (score 2):

según el repositorio de Mercadopago [Integrar MercadoPago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/478037/integrar-mercadopago)
dice que **PX-Android 4.28.0 es la última versión con un nivel mínimo de API 16**

- si tienes minSdkVersion 16 entonces usa la versión 4.28.0
- Si deseas usar la última versión del repositorio sin tener errores puedes colocar 4.+ quedaría así:
  implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.+'

Espero haberte podido ayudar con tu problema, Saludos.

Comment: Pues, la verdad sigue sucediendo lo mismo y estoy usando el minSDK 26

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo usar la versión 4.53.1, a mi me funciona perfectamente, si por alguna razón necesitas usar la última version podrías descargar la version 4.86.0 desde aquí https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android/releases/tag/4.86.0 y generar una version local con el comando: ./gradlew publishLocal

Comment: Me siegue saliendo el mismo error :/

Comment: Quizá el error sea la version de Gradle, al generar una version local me sale una advertencia: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0, prueba bajando a la version de Gradle 4.1.3